# Editing a cell in NSTableView auto tabs out

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have a NSTableView with 2 columns. Both are editable. When I hit on first column to edit values, it auto tabs out to the next column thus disallowing editing.
Any pointers, why?

Comment: As soon as I start typing a character, it auto tabs out to next column

Comment: You're not doing anything funky with `controlTextDidBeginEditing` notifications, are you?